# regex How to get text between ")" & "("

Tags: regex

Trying to get name of this string with is nested between ")" and "(".  tried the following but i am still getting the name plus ")". Example:  ")Jonathan".  I just need the name alone.

```
\)\b(\w+)\b
```

(AL,MO,TX,IA,MN,MI,KS,)Jonathan(WI,VA,NY,PA,DE,CT,PR,VI,)Jocelyn
AL,MO,TX,IA,MN,MI,KS,)Brian(

Comment: Your question is too broad since you didn't say what language or tool you use

Answer (score 0):

Try using lookaround assertions like this.

**Regex:** `(?<=\))[A-Za-z]+(?=\()`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\))` looks for `)` behind the name.
- `(?=\()` looks for `(` after name.
- `[A-Za-z]+` matches the name.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR7qA2/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use word border anchors `\b` because a parentheses to a letter will always be on a word border. Since you need the word alone, you could use lookahead and lookbehind expressions:

```
(?<=[)])\w+(?=[(])
```

This approach lets you do away with capturing groups, too, because lookarounds are zero-length.

Answer (score 0):

I use this regex to look for groups

```
/(?=\))(.*?)(?=\()/g
```

For some reason the ) char is not being excluded in http://regexr.com but lookahead and lookbehind are the right tools to use